# Find sum of List where property == true?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

In my C# code, I have a list of type `CustomClass`. This class contains a boolean property `trueOrFalse`.

I have a `List<CustomClass>`. I wish to create an integer using this List which holds the number of objects in the list which have a `trueOrFalse` value of `True`.

What is the best way to do this ? I assume there is a clever way to use Linq to accomplish this, rather than having to iterate over every object ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Servy - Of course I did. Count does not usually discriminate between boolean properties. I assumed some other magical tomfoolery had to be done to prevent Linq from merely counting the number of objects where the element is present.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx):

```
int numTrue = list.Count(cc => cc.trueOrFalse);
```

Remember to add `using system.Linq;`

Note that you should not use this method to check whether or not a sequence contains elements at all(`list.Count(cc => cc.trueOrFalse) != 0`). Therefore you should use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
bool hasTrue = list.Any(cc => cc.trueOrFalse);
```

The difference is that `Count` enumerates the whole sequence whereas `Any` will return true early as soon as it finds one element that passes the test predicate.

Comment: This helped me with a totally unrelated problem -- I just forgot whether, when you use List.Find or List.Any or whatnot, and your predicate is "myObject.BoolProperty == true", you don't need the "== true" -- just "myObject.BoolProperty"!

Answer (score 4):

You can do that indeed simple with LINQ.

```
int amountTrue = list.Where(c => c.trueOrFalse).Count();
```

Or shorter with the Where in the count:

```
int amountTrue = list.Count(c => c.trueOrFalse);
```

Like [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) stated: Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: You were just a second faster than i!

Answer (score 2):

```
 list.Count(a => a.TrueOrFalse);
```

And I've taken the liberty of giving your property a capital letter at start.

Answer (score 1):

That's trivial with LINQ:

```
list.Count(x => x.trueOrFalse);
```

Simply call the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) extension method on your list and pass in the condition. In your case, the condition is simply your boolean property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = listOfCustomClass.Where(a => a.trueOrFalse).Count();
```

Comment: My bad, corrected, but still, a few others got to the answer whilst I was typing, so no difference :) Thanks anyway.